# Removing links in UIWebView with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView being created programatically as follows;

```
- (void)loadView {
UIView *webNewsView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
self.view = webNewsView;    

CGRect webFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
webFrame.origin.y = 0.0f;
webNews = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];
webNews.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
webNews.scalesPageToFit = YES;
webNews.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
webNews.delegate = self;
webNews.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeNone;
[self.view addSubview: webNews];
[webNews loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://..........MYURL......./"]]];
```

}

I also have the following delegate methods;

I am attempting to remove all links within the UIWebView so my user cannot navigate away from the URL that I have coded in.  I have tried the following to change color of links;

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
[webNews stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.styleSheets[0].addRule(\"a.link\", \"color:#FFFFFF\")"];
}
```

I have read examples of people using javascript to remove all links from UIWebView but I can't seem to get this working.  Can anyone provide an example within the method of what I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the only way for the user to navigate from the page you're loading is by touching `A` elements?  What about form submit buttons or JavaScript event handlers that set `window.location`?

As far as I know, the bulletproof way to prevent navigation is to implement `webView: shouldStartLoadWithRequest: navigationType` to return `NO` except on the first request:

```
@interface MyDelegate <UIWebViewDelegate>
{
    BOOL didStartFirstRequest;
}
@end

@implementation MyDelegate
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if (didStartFirstRequest)
        return NO;
    didStartFirstRequest = YES;
    return YES;
}
@end
```

#### UPDATE

`UIWebView` has been deprecated for a while now in favor of `WKWebView`. If you are using `WKWebView`, you'll want to set its `navigationDelegate`, and in the delegate, implement the `webView(_:decidePolicyFor:preferences:decisionHandler:)` method.

Comment: I have previously tried implementing that method.  I noticed that it prohibited my webview from loading altogether.  The arguments were different to the ones you have mentioned however.  I will try this evening.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: The advice you provided above had the desired effect.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing here is making all the links with the "link" class look like normal text, not making them unclickable.  You could make the links do nothing with the following code:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a:link'), function(link) {link.href="javascript://"});
```

Of course,  they'll still look clickable.  You could actually remove them with something more like this:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a:link'), function(link) {
    while(link.firstChild && link.parentElement) {
        link.parentElement.insertBefore(link.firstChild, link);
        link.parentElement.removeChild(link);
    }
});
```

But this would have all sorts of other side effects.  It really depends on what you're trying to implement.

**UPDATE** switched from `parentNode` to `parentElement` and added check to skip parentless links.

Comment: I am displaying a recent company news page in the UIWebView, all of the information I want to show is on the page.  I want the user to be able to scroll the web view and that is all. I want /all/ links on the page to do nothing.

Comment: In that case, my second approach should work best.  It will simply remove the links and replace them with their contents.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt work. All links still remain clickable.

Comment: I've updated the code to something that should work more reliability.  It works successfully on a few pages I've tried.